# Display required fields on click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display required fields on click with javascript. I have large form and inside of that form I have some required fields. Idea is to have button so that user can click (like toggle) and see only required fields?

So far my approach is something like this:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {} else document.getElementById('ifYes').remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck">Click</button>
<div id="ifYes">
  <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="company" required>
</div>
```

What is the best way to this?

Comment: you have to use CSS visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show and hide optional fields using button click

```js
function toggleOptional(event){

  var button = event.currentTarget;
  
  var action = button.getAttribute('data-action');
  
  //var optionalFields =  document.querySelectorAll("form input:not([required])");
  
  var optionalFields =  document.querySelectorAll("form :not([required])");
  
  
  if(action == "hide"){
  
      optionalFields.forEach(function(value){
        value.style.display = "none";
      });
    
      button.setAttribute('data-action','show');
      
      button.innerText = "Show  Optional ";
  
  } else {
  
     optionalFields.forEach(function(value){
        value.style.display = "inline-block";
      });
    
      button.setAttribute('data-action','hide');
      
      button.innerText = "Hide Optional";
  }

}
```

```css
input,textarea,select {
  width : 70vw;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleOptional(event)" data-action="hide"  >Hide Optional</button>


<form>


    <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="usrname" required>
    
    
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone" required >
     
    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="company" >
    
    <select  name="birthyear" required  >
      <option value="">Select Year of Birth</option>
      <option value="1992">1992</option>
      <option value="1993">1993</option>
    </select>
    
    <textarea required name="description" placeholder="description" ></textarea>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to toggle the optional fields, you could just hide all optional elements in form (like in this example).

Keep in mind that yu may want to change the css selector to have more control what elements you want to hide.

eg:

```
form input:not([required]),
form select:not([required]),
form textarea:not([required]), ....
```

You may also want to not just hiden those fields but style them differently (opacity or something like that).

```js
function toggleOptionalFields() {
  document.querySelectorAll('form > :not([required])').forEach(field => field.hidden = !field.hidden);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required value="i am required" />
  <input />
  <select required>
    <option value="1">required! :)</option>
  </select>
  <input />
  <input />
  <input required value="i am required too" />
</form>

<button onclick="toggleOptionalFields()">Toggle optional fields</button>
```

Also this function will *not* in IE because `querySelectorAll().forEach` and the arrow function are not supportet.

You could easily change that by using a regular function instead of the arrow-function and iterate differenttly thru the elementlist (eg, `for(;;)` or `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(), function(element) {...});`, ...).

Comment: Yeah you are right I didnt considered selects and textareas

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in javascript then here is a simple solution

**Javascript**

```
function yesnoCheck() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ifYes");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
#ifYes{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap all fields in the container like `<div>` or `<form>`

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
  <input required />
  <input />
  <input required />
</div>
```

then your toggle button function should toggle a class in the container

**Javascript**

```
function yesnoCheck() {
  let container = document.querySelector('.container')
  container.classList.toggle('only-required')
}
```

now you can use CSS to hide the non-required field if the container has a class `only-required`

**CSS**

```css
.container.only-required input:not([required]) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a boolean variable and toggle its value and show or hide your elements based on it.

```js
var toggleIfYes=false;
    function yesnoCheck() {
toggleIfYes=!toggleIfYes
      if (toggleIfYes) {
         //show the elements
     } else{
         //hide the elements
      }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck">Click</button>
<div id="ifYes">
  <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="company" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using `document.getElementById('ifYes').remove()` which removes the element from the DOM. This way you won't be able to recover your element when you click the toggle button again. Also, you're verifying a `<button/>` element as if it were an `<input type="checkbox" />` so you might want to use a checkbox instead.

You'd be better off using `document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none'` as it fits best in this situation:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" id="yesCheck">Click</input>
<div id="ifYes">
  <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="company" required>
</div>
```

Comment: It always impresses me how the downvoters won't ever mind saying the reason why they did it.